# Can subscriptions clash in MQTT (Paho)?

Tags: mqtt, paho, pahocpp

I have a question about subscriptions in Paho and how applications can manage disparate topics (allowing for wildcards). We're interested because we're providing a layer to manage all this stuff to both simplify life for the developers and so we can later use non-MQTT pub/sub under the covers if desired.

An example is probably the best way to explain. Let's say we have two separate modules in our program:

- `get_all_info()` subscribes for a *short* time to the topic `fleet/vehicle-N/#` to get all information for a specific vehicle `N`.
- `speed_mon()`, interested only in the speed of all vehicles, subscribes to `fleet/+/speed` for the duration of the program.

Consider the sequence<sup>(a)</sup>:

- `speed_mon()` subscribes to `fleet/+/speed`.
- `get_all_info()` subscribes to `fleet/vehicle-17/#` and gets information.
- `get_all_info()` unsubscribes to `fleet/vehicle-17/#`.

Will the third operation affect the first? In other words, will we still get messages of topic `fleet/vehicle-17/speed`?

If the unsubscribe is a simple reversal of a *specific* subscription, it will disable only the subscription created in the second bullet point.

If it uses the filter to disable all *matching* subscriptions (in the sense of wildcards), it will affect the first subscription as well.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Ignore the fact for now that we would be better off with `get_all_info()` subscribing to `fleet/#` for the duration of the program and never unsubscribing, instead just caching messages into local storage. This is a contrived example. We have no control over *how* clients will use our layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the MQTT specs are pretty clear on this. The  [v3](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc384800449) and [v5](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc473620212) text is similar; v3 states:

> The Topic Filters (whether they contain wildcards or not) supplied in an UNSUBSCRIBE packet MUST be compared character-by-character with the current set of Topic Filters held by the Server for the Client. If any filter matches exactly then its owning Subscription is deleted, otherwise no additional processing occurs [MQTT-3.10.4-1].

So it's a character-by-character comparison; unsubscribing to `fleet/vehicle-17/#` will have no impact on the subscription to `fleet/+/speed`.

Note that some libraries may not implement this correctly when it comes to mapping incoming messages to callbacks (the go library used to [have this wrong](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/pull/388)).

Perhaps a more interesting question is (you did not ask this but it may have an impact):

> If I'm subscribed to both `fleet/+/speed` and `fleet/vehicle-17/#` will I get multiple copies of messages on the `fleet/vehicle-17/speed` topic.

The behaviour here is a little more subject to implementation detail in v3 ( [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718042)) but clearly defined in v5 due to the introduction of subscription identifiers ([spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901120)).